# AngularJS controller throwing an error while injecting factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

I'm new to Angular and I'm building my first angular app. I have my portfolio webpage where I want to get data from an external source and make it available to all the controllers.

This is what I have for html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="portfolioApp">
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Mithun Mathew</title>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='images/favicon.ico' type='image/x-icon'/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" type="text/css">

    <!-- Angular Import-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Main Module -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="portfolioApp.js"></script>

    <!-- Angular Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/dataRetrieve.js"></script>



</head>
<body ng-controller="FirstCtrl">

<me></me>

</body>
</html>
```

My js files:
portfolioApp.js

```
angular.module('portfolioApp',[])
.factory('Data', ['$scope', '$http', function DataFactory ($scope, $http) {
    var dataCtrl = this;

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://someurl/'
    }).success(function (data) {
        dataCtrl.data = data;
        console.log(data);
    }).error(function (error) {
        console.log("Hey! Something went wrong while loading.  :(");
    });


    return function(){
        return dataCtrl.data;
    }
}]);
```

dataRetrieve.js

```
angular.module('portfolioApp',[])
    .controller('FirstCtrl', function(Data) {
        console.log('Hello');
        console.log(Data());
    });
```

Angular throws me an error when I inject Data into the controller. How do I get past this? I googled, watched YouTube videos and CodeSchool, and couldn't figure out why the error is thrown.

Comment: What error? I don't see one

Comment: Phil, I'm not able to use the factory properly. I think there is an issue where I inject Data factory into FirstCtrl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

note that when you creating second new module with same name with `[]` first module will override.

for ex:

you create

```
angular.module('portfolioApp',[]).factory('....
```

angular will create a new module called `portfolioApp` because of there is `[]` after the module name.

then

```
angular.module('portfolioApp',[])
.controller('FirstCtrl',....
```

you try to create a module with same name as before with `[]` so angular will override the first module with this one, so your previous module is no more at this time, so there is no factory called `Data`

so simply remove `[]` from the second module declaration then angular will not going to override the previous module instead angular will extends the module,

```
angular.module('portfolioApp')
    .controller('FirstCtrl', fu...
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this, but I still cannot get the data printed using console.log(Data()). 

I get an error where I inject Data into the controller. Am I missing something else. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: remove the `$scope` injection from factory. :) here is a demo. check with console http://plnkr.co/edit/hdNJWe237IgDPBZ4YKab?p=preview